# Import Google Analytics to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration

I am trying to figure out how to import Google Analytics data into AWS Redshift.  Until now I have been able to setup an export job so the data makes it to Google's BigQuery and then exporting the tables to Google's Cloud Storage.

BigQuery stores data in particular way, so when you export it to a file, it gives you a multilevel nested JSON structure. So, in order to import it to Redshift, I would have to "explode" that JSON into a table or CSV file.

I haven't been able to find a simple solution to do this.

Does anyone know how I can do this in an elegant and efficient way, instead of having to write a long function that will go through the whole JSON object?

Here's Google's documentation about how to export data https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Export your BigQuery data as json into the S3 bucket
2. Create [JSONPaths file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json-jsonpaths) according to specification
3. Include JSONPaths file in your [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#copy-from-json-examples-using-jsonpaths) to import into the Redshift

You may also try to export your BigQuery table as **AVRO** (one of the supported export file formas in BigQuery) instead of json. [This link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json-jsonpath-expressions) has an example of how to write the JSONPaths file for nested AVRO objects.

Comment: Thanks! I tried multiple options, from JSON to AVRO, using JSONPaths and couldn't make it work.  After reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-avro), I figured it can't be done in a straight forward way.  They state that
 `Amazon Redshift does not support any JSONPath elements, such as wildcard characters or filter expressions, that might resolve to an ambiguous path or multiple name elements.`

For example, I don't know how many `hits` a record is going to have, so somehow I would need to use the wildcard character.

Comment: Then you could write a Scala/Python script that reads AVRO into the DataFrame in Spark, explodes the fields and then either writes directly to Redshift or saves back to S3 in format that can be used with COPY command.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to avoid =) I was hoping to find something easier and more elegant.  Thanks!